# Is this the first time an appeal about double jeopardy for being tried first in the US senate, then in the judiciary has been considered?

Tags: united-states, federal-courts, appeal, double-jeopardy

An exchange between two CNN reporters in a December 14, 2023 video [Judge pauses Trump election interference case](https://youtu.be/yi3BX9lBb5c) begins

> BLITZER: ...the judge ordering a pause until major appeals play out, potentially delaying Trump's march trial date. Here's CNN senior crime and justice reporter Katelyn Polantz. Katelyn, why is the judge making this move?
>
> POLANTZ: Well, essentially she has to. She doesn't really have another option because in Donald Trump's criminal case, before he goes to trial, the courts have to figure out two things. (1) **If Donald Trump can even be tried, he was already tried by the Senate. Is that double jeopardy now that he's charged again in a criminal court of law? So they have to decide that.** (2) And also they have to decide a question about presidential immunity...

Is this the first time that such a claim of double jeopardy<sup>1</sup> has had to be consider by a court of appeals? Or are there some previous rulings?

---

<sup>1</sup>first in the US Senate (legislative branch of government), then again in the judicial branch.

Comment: This shouldn't be hard to figure out as there has only been 20 total impeachment trials in the senate and two of those are for Trump. Should be a quick search to see if any of the others got tried criminally for their crimes. Though both Jack Smith and Trumps lawyers would have to be pretty bad to not have brought up any past rulings on this as they would have to be in one sides favor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_impeachment_trial_in_the_United_States#List_of_trials

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about the argument's merits -- just its novelty.

Comment: @bdb484 And I am suggesting that it is easy to verify that it has never happened before as an impeachment has only happened 20 total times in history with two of them being Trump. What is happening right now with Trump has never happened before in the history of our country. With so few impeachments in history if it had happened one side or the other would be covering it non stop to support their case.

Comment: Agreed all around. My comment was directed to @Trish, who has since deleted her comment about the case being frivolous.

Comment: @bdb484 Okay, that makes sense can get confusing when comments get deleted.

Comment: For what it's worth, neither [Trump's original filing](https://www.lawfaremedia.org/article/trump-files-motion-to-dismiss-jan.-6-case-on-constitutional-grounds) nor [Judge Chutkan's ruling](https://www.lawfaremedia.org/article/chutkan-denies-trump-s-motions-to-dismiss) mention any direct precedents.  You would think that if there was a precedent, one of them would have mentioned it.

Comment: @JoeW the comment turned out to become an answer, so I removed it.

Answer (score 55):

Nobody has ever tried this argument before because most people are not so foolish as to overlook the fact that the Constitution ([Article I, Section 3, Clause 7](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/article-1/section-3/clause-7/)) explicitly provides for the possibility of a judicial trial in addition to an impeachment:

> Judgment in Cases of Impeachment shall not extend further than to removal from Office, and disqualification to hold and enjoy any Office of honor, Trust or Profit under the United States: but the Party convicted shall nevertheless be liable and subject to Indictment, Trial, Judgment and Punishment, according to Law.

The argument isn't simply without merit; it is frivolous.

Comment: I don't think this language really does anything to help the government's case, as it only applies to officers who have been *convicted* after impeachment. Trump's argument is that he can't be tried again because he was *acquitted*.

Comment: @bdb484 The issue is that impeachment isn't criminal in nature and people can get impeached for perfectly legal matters.

Comment: "the Party convicted" - Trump was acquitted. If you're convicted, you can get dragged though the regular judicial process as normal. Getting acquitted is not addressed, and looks a lot like double jeopardy.

Comment: @fectin it would make very little sense to say that you can be tried multiple times only if you've been convincted. It's pretty clear that impeachment isn't jeopardy unless you use a particularly loose reading of the constitution

Comment: @PCLuddite Isn't that how it is for typical cases of double jeopardy? If you are acquitted at trial, you cannot be tried again for the same crime. If you are convicted and have the decision reversed on appeal, it is in some cases possible for you to be re-tried. As I understand it, in any normal criminal case that gets tried more than once, the defendant cannot have been acquitted the first time. Agree that the bigger issue is that an impeachment merely threatening removal from office is not criminal jeopardy to begin with.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie if an appeal is granted, it's not a new trial. It's an opportunity to bring forward evidence that the original trial was flawed. The original trial is effectively void because it was decided you were never fairly tried in the first place.

Comment: @fectin No, the correct analogy is civil vs criminal proceedings. 5th Amendment explicitly says "jeopardy of life or limb," which does not preclude other remedies, like money. A famous example, OJ Simpson was found not guilty of murder, whereas he was civilly responsible for wrongful death in a separate proceeding. Getting fired from your government job is not "jeopardy of life or limb". Related, you can be criminally tried twice under Federal and State charges, "separate sovereigns" (Gamble v. United States).

Comment: @bdb484 the protection against double jeopardy applies after an acquittal as well as after a conviction.  In fact it is almost always invoked after acquittal.

Comment: @fectin double jeopardy means that you cannot be tried for a crime after already being tried for the crime, regardless of the outcome of the first trial.  The fact that you can be tried on indictment after being _convicted_ on impeachment clearly implies that you can be tried on indictment after being _acquitted_ on impeachment because it implies that double jeopardy doesn't apply to impeachments.

Comment: @phoog while there is a reasonable argument that a narrow specific exception to a well-established general rule actually implies a broader, unwritten exception to that general rule, I don't think a bare citation of the narrow exception really makes that argument.

Comment: @fectin Impeachment isn't trying someone from a crime rather it is deciding if they should be removed from office for some reason. One of the important differences between impeachment and a criminal trial is there are no rules of evidence in impeachment among other things. https://thehill.com/homenews/senate/478089-how-impeachment-differs-from-court-trials/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CThere%20aren't%20any%20rules,charged%20with%20an%20actual%20crime.

Comment: @phoog I think we all agree on that. But it's not really relevant to your answer about the impeachment clause. They're totally separate analyses.

Comment: @fectin what general rule?  There's no general rule that would apply here.  "Double jeopardy" is the common name of a rule based on the "life or limb" clause of the fifth amendment, but in its application it depends on several specific details developed through judicial precedent concerning when jeopardy "attaches" in a criminal trial.  There's no general formulation of the rule that would apply to congressional impeachments.

Comment: @phoog your position is clear; further discussion is beyond the scope of comments. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 27):

### It is the first time

Currently, [there were **4** impeachment trials of presidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_efforts_to_impeach_presidents_of_the_United_States#Presidents_who_have_been_impeached):

- Johnson in 1868, over longstanding arguments
- Clinton in 1998/99, over an affair
- Trump in 2019/20, over interference with the Ukrainian Government
- Trump in 2021, over the riots of January 6th 2021, including alleged election fraud

As one will easily see, this is the **first** case that ever has, after an impeachment trial, brought any such argument.

### The argument brought by Trump's lawyers has no merit

Double jeopardy is banned in the fifth amendment of the constitution. It reads:

> No person shall be held to answer for a capital, or otherwise infamous crime, unless on a presentment or indictment of a Grand Jury, except in cases arising in the land or naval forces, or in the Militia, when in actual service in time of War or public danger; **nor shall any person be subject for the same offence to be twice put in jeopardy of life or limb;** nor shall be compelled in any criminal case to be a witness against himself, nor be deprived of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor shall private property be taken for public use, without just compensation.

The bolded sentence is the alleged core of the argument, but also its biggest weakness.
The problem with framing the impeachment trial as "jeopardy of life or limb" is, that the impeachment trial can only have a single outcome in case of conviction: removal from office. Removal from office does not put someone in danger of being executed or incarcerated, so the senate trial does **not** attach the required jeopardy in the first place. As such, the Georgia trial is the **first** trial that puts Donald Trump in "jeopardy of life or limb".

And there's a second problem: "the same offence" means being tried twice for the same act using the same laws. However, even *if* one were to assume that the senate trial was giving jeopardy of life or limb, he was not tried in any way under Georgia law but a quite different offence in a court that is not Georgia. Georgia is **sovereign**: A person can be tried by **both** federal and state courts for the same act for violating different laws. That's the [dual sovereignty doctrine.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution-conan/amendment-5/dual-sovereignty-doctrine) In fact, [Palko v. Connecticut, 302 U.S. 319 (1937)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/302/319) and [United States v. Lanza
260 U.S. 377 (1922)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/260/377) both explicitly rejected that the double jeopardy clause bolded above barred a state from bringing a case where unsuccessful federal charges had been brought, and vice versa. Lanza brings it to a point with:

> 11
> We have here two sovereignties, deriving power from different sources, capable of dealing with the same subject matter within the same territory. **Each may, without interference by the other, enact laws to secure prohibition**, with the limitation that no legislation can give validity to acts prohibited by the amendment. **Each government in determining what shall be an offense against its peace and dignity is exercising its own sovereignty, not that of the other.**

**As such, the double jeopardy argument is utterly meritless**, as Donald Trump has never been adjudicated in any court before, neither a federal nor a Georgia court for any *federal crime* or *Georgia crime* arising from the acts of alleged manipulation of the election.

He was tried in the Senate - which is **not** a court of law. [It is explicitly **not** a judicial process but a **political** one](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73596/legal-or-political-nature-of-impeachment-of-a-us-president) that wears the trappings of a judicial process. As such, the prosecution has **not** exhausted its bite at the apple.

See also:

- [Does Double Jeopardy prohibit prosecution, for the same event, in both Federal and State court?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/72782/does-double-jeopardy-prohibit-prosecution-for-the-same-event-in-both-federal-a)
- [Legal or Political nature of Impeachment of a US President](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73596/legal-or-political-nature-of-impeachment-of-a-us-president)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't specify *presidential* impeachments - I think the US House can [impeach other executive branch appointees as well](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artII-S4-2/ALDE_00000689/), with names like DHS secretary Mayorkas being suggested. Also, while I didn't ask about the merits (even though a [misleading comment makes it look like I did](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97969/is-this-the-first-time-an-appeal-about-double-jeopardy-for-being-tried-first-in/97979#comment227991_97969)) it  is nice to have that here.

Comment: @uhoh the no executive officer other than a president has ever been impeached.  Judges have been impeached.

Comment: @uhoh besides mostly judges being thrown out of office by impeachment and four presidents, the following impeachment cases moved forward: [one Senator was tried, but the case dismissed after he was already expelled,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Blount#Blount_Conspiracy) [one secretary of war was tried in senate, acquitted there but charged with being bribed in DC Federal court, but there was backdoor shenanigans that lead to the DA dismissing the case: president Grant asked for it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_W._Belknap#Washington,_D.C.,_indictment_(1876%E2%80%931877))

Comment: Got it - thanks! :-)

Comment: I think this reaches the right answer, but for the wrong reason. The dual sovereign issue isn't really at play, as we're talking about the DC case, not the Georgia case.

Comment: The Clinton impeachment wasn't for the affair, it was for lying to Congress about the affair ("I did not have sexual relations with that woman.")

Comment: The OP is about the *federal* criminal case being overseen by Judge Chutkan, so the dual sovereignty matter is irrelevant to that particular case. Yes, there is also a Georgia criminal case, but the OP isn't about that case.

Comment: 1. Clearly "life or limb" isn't to be taken literally; otherwise, it would not apply in cases where the penalty is imprisonment. 2. Impeachment can result in a person being barred from office.

Comment: @Barmar I believe it was for lying in a deposition in the Paula Jones civil case, not lying to Congress.

Comment: @Acccumulation Whioch is the **only** punishment it can have, and since that is neither incarceration or death, it is not *life or limb*

Comment: [20 different people have been impeached](https://history.house.gov/Institution/Impeachment/Impeachment-List/). Presidents aren't the only ones who can be impeached. Several of those impeachments were for criminal matters. Also, Clinton was impeached for perjury and obstruction of justice, not for having an affair.

Comment: @reirab Of the 20 people, **one** was an Ex-senator, **one** was an Ex-War minister, and **14** were Judges. **none** of these were members of the executive when they were tried: the senator became the example of that senate can not indict senators, and the war minister was out of office and thus they dropped the indictment.

Comment: @Trish Why would the branch matter? Not that the double jeopardy argument has merit, but, if it did, I'm not sure why it would apply differently to a judge than to a President. (My point here is that the first section either needs to be expanded to cover each of the cases or else removed, as it does not currently seem to prove its point.)

Comment: @Trish the Senate can't indict anyone -- not impeach anyone.  They can only try those who have been impeached by the house of representatives.

Comment: @phoog wrong word, yes, but they chose that they can't try such people.

Comment: It's just as flamboyantly idiotic as saying "My homeowner's association has already fined me for dumping garbage in the street, therefore I cannot be charged with littering because double jeopardy." Ditto for "I've already been disbarred as an attorney for my fraudulent behavior, therefore I cannot stand trial for fraud because double jeopardy." Double jeopardy doesn't mean "getting in trouble twice."

Comment: My previous comment should have said "cannot indict nor impeach" rather than "cannot indict not impeach."  But the Senate also cannot choose to try anyone -- the accused has to be impeached first by the House of Representatives before there can be a trial in the Senate.  The Senate cannot act alone.  And the prohibition on impeaching members if congress is rather unimportant in the face of the ability of each house to expel its own members by acting alone.